# how do i setup raid on my harddrives

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, raid, gparted

yes hello I have 5 2tb hard drives in my computer I use it to record TV as a DVR for my TV one 2tb section has Ubuntu 14.04 on it. I would like to use all the hard drives for TV show. how do I do this please be descriptive and if needed I can section off each drive if I have to to be like TV shows movies ect but I would rather not if possible. if this is not raid please tell me I can use gparted if needed its already installed.

Answer (score 0):

If your motherboard offers this, there is generally a Hard Drive setting in the BIOs that will allow you to change the setup from IDE to RAID. Once you have made that change, you should be able to configure RAID but you would need to make sure that your motherboard supports SATA RAID or something similar, depending on your setup.

Comment: my system is gigabyte model name is am1m-s2h bios version f1 bios date 01/27/2014 bios id  8a04bg04

Comment: I'm not sure how related this is to Ubuntu, but that motherboard doesn't appear to support RAID. http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4937#sp

Comment: ok so what do i need todo to set up my hard drive as 1 big drive or set it up into sections

Comment: That would be up to you. There isn't any redundancy with multiple partitions which is the entire purpose of RAID. I'd leave it as one and manually backup your data elsewhere.

Comment: yes but how do i setup for multiple drives